# C++ Vector item being deleted after push_back()

Tags: c++, vector

I'm having a problem pushing an object to a vector.

I have three classes involved in this: Pack.h, Player.h, Hand.h

Pack deals the cards, Player accepts the card from the Pack and then Hand accepts the card from the Player.

The functions:

The Pack dealing the cards

```
bool Pack::Deal(std::vector<Player>players, unsigned int numberOfCards)
{
    //This assumes that if we cannot deal the requested number of cards we do not deal any cards at all.
    //If we wanted to deal as many cards as possibly we would check for errors while iterating over players.

    if (m_pack_of_cards.size() < players.size() * numberOfCards) //check that we have enough cards to complete deal
    {
        std::cout << "Not enough cards to complete deal." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numberOfCards; i++)
        {
            for (auto player : players)
            {
                player.Accept_Card_From_Pack(m_pack_of_cards.back());
                m_pack_of_cards.pop_back();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The Player accepting the card from the Pack

```
bool Player::Accept_Card_From_Pack(Card card)
{
    m_player_hand.Accept_Card_From_Player(card);
    return true;
}
```

The Hand accepting the card from the Player

```
bool Hand::Accept_Card_From_Player(Card card)
{   
    m_hand_of_cards.push_back(card);
    return true;
}
```

My main function

```
int main()
{
    Pack pack = Pack();
    std::vector<Player> players(4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        players[i] = Player("Player: " + std::to_string(i));
    }

    pack.Deal(players, 8);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

What this does is create a new Pack create some players, deal some cards to each of those players.

It's the players taking the cards that is the problem, the Pack calls the players accept card function, the Player's accept card function calls the Hand's accept card function, the Hand should then push the card back onto it's vector of cards.

It does push it back, if I std::cout the size of the vector before and after the push_back it goes from 0 to 1, it isn't keeping the item though, so the next time I push something back it will again give me 0 and 1 as the size of the vector before and after the push_back.

Oh and this is a University assignment (do I have to put that here? I can't remember).

Answer (score 3):

Figured out the problem, this usually happens right after I post a question but I'll answer it here in case anyone has a similar problem.

The issue was in this bit of the Player Deal function:

```
for (auto player : players)
        {
            player.Accept_Card_From_Pack(m_pack_of_cards.back());
            m_pack_of_cards.pop_back();
        }
```

That should be:

```
for (auto &player : players)
            {
                player.Accept_Card_From_Pack(m_pack_of_cards.back());
                m_pack_of_cards.pop_back();
            }
```

As mentioned below Eelke and Underscore_d, should also be passing the argument:

```
std::vector<Player>players
```

as

```
std::vector<Player>&players
```

Comment: I was going to say anyway, the usual recommendation is to handle all passed/iterated objects (non-primitive types) by reference. It avoids all sorts of confusion around copied/changed objects, such as this one.

Comment: You should also pass the vector of players by reference to the deal function.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Imo your default position should be to use a reference, unless you have a specific need to use a copy (which by-value implicitly creates). People usually exclude function arguments of primitive type from this rule, e.g. because passing those by reference is often less efficient (pointer size/dereference tradeoff), and I think those are less frequently changed by functions anyway.

Comment: @underscore_d: And just to avoid any confusion, this is all about parameter-passing. Return values are a different story altogether.

Comment: Good point. I mentioned those initially but not in my subsequent comment, since they weren't related, but it's worth pointing out they don't follow the same maxims as parameters - and in many cases iterators. I'll try to do that next time.